# Non-transitive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have the set $A = \left \{1, 6, 0 \right \}$ and the relation $R = \left \{(1,6), (6,1), (1,0), (0,6), (6,1) \right \}$
Is that relation transitive? If I am right it is not because I don't have $(1,1)$.
Is that a correct reason for saying that it is not transitive? And why it is antisymmetric?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct. What are you unsure of?

Comment: i was thinking that the last bracket of (6,1) it should be (1,6) and not (6,1). It doesnt matter?

Comment: Both $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ are duplicates of other members on your list, so something seems off.

Comment: Either way, the last bracket is a copy of one of the first two, and therefore redundant. You should also specify why transitivity would require $(1,1)$ to be in the relation: point out explicitly that you're using $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$.

Comment: okay i see. but the  brackets "((1,0),(0,6))" they shouldnt be followed of a bracket (1,6) instead of (6,1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

If $(a,b) $ and $ (b,c)$ are in the relation, and if $(a,c)$ is not, then the relation not transitive.

In your case, where $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in the relation, both $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ need to be present for the relation to be transitive.

---

Anti-symmetric means that when $(a,b)$  is in the relation, where $a\ne b$, then $(b,a)$ **must not** be in the relation. As you can see, that is not the case in the given relation, so the given relation is not anti-symmetric.

Comment: The second paragraph is false: a relation can be both symmetric and anti-symmetric at the same time.

Comment: @mrp Thank you! Fixed. That was a major error. My bad. I'm sorry.